# creating box for each letter of a dynamic-sized word in an input Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, input

I'm making a little React app where a user tries to guess a scrambled word on the screen. I'm fetching random words from an external API, but each word has a different length. Instead of a normal input, I want a box-like input where a box is rendered for each letter in the word. Since the word is of dynamic size and not static, I'm having trouble styling my input to get the desired result. For example, for the word "alphabets" which has 9 letters, I would want to render the following input:

[image]

where each grey box represents a single character, and as you type, the letter you guess would fill in the box. My current code using a regular input:

```js
const WordGuess = ({ word }) => { // word is fetched in App.js and passed down as a prop
   const [isInputDisabled, setIsInputDisabled] = useState(false);
   const [userGuess, setUserGuess] = useState('');
   
   // disabling the input when the user guesses the correct word
   useEffect(() => {
      if (word) {
         setIsInputDisabled(userGuess === word ? true : false);
      }
   }, [userGuess]);

   return (
      <div>
         <input value={userGuess} 
                onChange={e => setUserGuess(e.target.value)} 
                disabled={isInputDisabled}
         />
         {isInputDisabled && (
            <div><p>You guessed correctly!</div>
         )}
      </div>
    )
})

export default UserGuess;
```

Comment: What do you want to happen about the user wanting to edit their input so far - backspacing and clicking on a random character?

Comment: @AHaworth It will act like a regular input, where the user can backspace to delete what they have already written. As for clicking on random characters, I didn't plan to add support for that but I thought it would come out of the box if I could simply style an input tag to get the same effect.